# Test questions probability

Tags: probability

Suppose I give you a list of 21 problems to study, from which I will randomly pick 12 questions for your first midterm exam.

For whatever reason, you prepare for the midterm exam by completing and understanding how to solve 11 questions of the 21, so there are 10 questions you do not know how to solve.

Part (a) What is the probability that you completely solve 8 of the 12 questions appearing on the midterm exam?

Part (b) To pass the midterm, you must correctly solve at least half of the 12 questions. What is the probability of you passing the midterm exam?

I'm a little confused on how to proceed, help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In how many ways can the teacher pick which twelve problems are on the test?  In how many ways can the teacher pick exactly eight of the questions the student knows about followed by picking four of the questions the student doesn't know about?  Use binomial coefficients and the rule of product.  Conclude by using ratios.

Comment: For part a)  you'll answer 8 questions if the instructor picks 8 questions from the 11 you studied and 4 questions from the 10 you didn't study.  Can you calculate the number of ways this can occur?  Also, you need to know how many ways the instructor can pick the 12 questions on the exam.  Do you know how to do that?  Once you have those two figures, can you compute probability?

Comment: I tried (11 choose 8 * 10 choose 8)/ (21 choose 12) but this was wrong. Is this way off course? @JMoravitz

Comment: It is closer than you think, but you need to be sure you understand why each number is the number it is in what you are using.  What does (11 choose 8) have to do with the problem?  What does (10 choose 8) have to do with the problem?  One of those two 8's should have been something else.  Similarly, why 14 in (21 choose 14)?  Shouldn't it have been another number?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah it was a typo, should have been 12. I'm not sure why one of the eights would be different. And for part b, I should just add up all the probabilities of getting 6 or more correct, yes? Using the same calculations from a?

Comment: I refer you again to my initial comment then.  "*In how many ways can the teacher pick exactly* **eight** *of the questions the student knows about followed by picking* **four** *of the questions the student doesn't know about?*"

Comment: @JMoravitz 10 choose 4 got it thanks